# Oracle query is not working in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle11g

When I run this code it always returning zero while when i run this query in oracle sql client it returns 1.

```
 var strSQL = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GANTNER.GAT_REASONS WHERE CODE ='{0}'", StatusCode);    
 objCmd = new OracleCommand(strSQL, objConn);
 objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 int val = int.Parse(objCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

For try I remove condition on column name `CODE` and it works but when I put column name `CODE` it does not then I tried to put `"CODE"` `'CODE'` all not working always returning zero while it should return 1 because row exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be letter *case* problem.Try `UPPER/UCASE` function to compare.

```
var strSQL = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GANTNER.GAT_REASONS
              WHERE UCASE(CODE) ='{0}'", StatusCode.ToUpper());
```

Or

```
var strSQL ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GANTNER.GAT_REASONS WHERE CODE =:code";
objCmd = new OracleCommand(strSQL, objConn);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("code",StatusCode.ToUpper());
```

Comment: Is this numeric field? not no need to wrap value with single quote.

Comment: its string field but contain numeric value 142

Comment: My guess! The **CODE** is of **CHAR** type . OR You've insert some rows via SQL prompt and you haven't **commit** these changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = conn.createCommand();
// parametrized sql query
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GANTNER.GAT_REASONS WHERE CODE = :status";
// add parameter for the query
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", StatusCode); 
int val = int.Parse(objCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Comment: I already tried with Parameters query but it still not working because issue with column name

Comment: @SOFUser What issue? Do you have an error code. What exactly is `StatusCode`?

Comment: StatusCode = "142" and row exist in database but it is returning count zero. while in sql developer it is returning row count 1

Comment: @SOFUser Commit, try again, if it doesn't work copy-paste your exact query from sql developer.