# execute.scalar with SQL and where clause always returns 0

Tags: c#, oracle

when I try to read a number of records from oracle db, I have a strange behavior. I use this code:

```
string sqlStatement = "select count(*) from EMP where code=1";
OleDbCommand chargeCount = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, conn);

if (chargeCount.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    chargeCount.Connection.Close();
else
    chargeCount.Connection.Open();

Console.WriteLine("No of records: {0}",
chargeCount.ExecuteScalar());
```

it returns always 0, but should return 100000 (as I receive with the above SQL statement in SQLplus).

If I change the sql statement to "select count(*) from EMP", I receive the correct number of records.

Looks like somewhere I have a mistake. Can somebody please put me in the right direction?

Comment: At the moment there is ODP.Net out there and it is the preferred way to connect to Oracle, can you use it instead?

Comment: Maybe same problem? `Code` column case problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664253/oracle-query-is-not-working-in-c-sharp